# How to spoof time zone in Selenium on windows for gecko and chrome drivers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to launch a spoofed time zone per browser profile in Selenium.   Is there a way to do this in Python on windows?  I have read that it can be done in Ruby and Java.

This works in Unix:

```
import os, time
time.strftime('%X %x %Z')
'12:45:20 08/19/09 CDT'
os.environ['TZ'] = 'Europe/London'
time.tzset()
time.strftime('%X %x %Z')
'18:45:39 08/19/09 BST'
```

I want to change browser time zone and not system time zone.

Comment: You may like to have a look at this [**`JavaScript`**](https://codeforhire.com/2013/08/11/testing-time-dependent-features-in-javascript/) based solution or this [**`Ruby`**](https://makandracards.com/makandra/10753-mock-the-browser-time-or-time-zone-in-selenium-features) based solution.

Comment: @DebanjanB Can I just add timeshift Js to the Python Library?  I don't see any documentation on that and Python does not like the code from there...

Comment: Too early for me to comment as I just started with JS bindings :)

Comment: @DebanjanB https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/wiki/Setting-a-Timezone .  Not sure if possible with windows.

Comment: Yup, seems pretty feasible with Docker

Comment: @DebanjanB Any ideas on how I install this in Python windows.  I usually use pip install from command line but from what it looks like it might be Linux only.

Answer (score 0):

Possible....? Sort of.  I imagine others have a better way of doing it.

CMD for CHROME:

```
SET TZ=GMT-5

 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Person 2"
```

FF:

```
SET TZ=GMT-5
 “C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe “  -P Person2 -no-remote"\
```

You’d have to launch CMD from Python each time you load browser (never done this before so don’t ask how)

Then load whoer.net and test if your time zone has changed.

Limitations of this method

- You have to close all browsers before it lets you change the TZ variable.  That means you can only have one TZ spoof per Browser.
- I have had mixed results with Chrome working.  It worked and then it stopped listening to me.
- What about a better method then? None that I know of.  I believe you can inject the time zone with javascript but that is far beyond by knowledge.
  Surprised there’s no plugins for this on Chrome or FF considering how popular such a feature would be…. $$$.  Monopoly market as well.